# Firebase rules to give read access to a dynamic list of users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Let's say I have 3 Nodes like this:

```
User    
    Uid1
    Uid2
    Uid3

Group
    groupId1
        uid1 : true
        uid3 : true

Meeting
    meetId1
        members : groupId1
        topic : "my topic"
        etc….
    meetId2
        members : groupId2
        etc...
```

Each group, each meeting can be created dynamically.

How can I write a Rule to allow read access to a meeting to only its group members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `.read` rule should give read permission to the group's members:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Meeting": {
      "$meetingId": {
        ".read": "auth !== null && root.child('Group').child(data.child('members').val()).child(auth.uid).val() === true"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks that sound great but the Rules simulator give me the following syntax error : "Simulation failed - Line 19: Right operand of && must be boolean.'. ???

Comment: Yep. There was an error. It needs a `val()` - or `exists()`, if the values are always `true` - on the end.